# Is there a site that tracks volume over time?

Tags: altcoin, historical-trade-data, volume

Coinmarketcap shows the current volume data. Is there a site that tracks volume over time in a graph and data table where you can sort by highest volume days? I'm looking to see if a specific coin has been increasing volume over time.

Comment: coinmarketcap keeps track of volume data for every day. https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/

Comment: @patoshi: Many of your questions create new tags that are duplicates of existing tags or unnecessary. E.g. your question here uses Coinmarketcap as an example of _what you're not looking for_. It doesn't make sense to me that you then create that as a new tag here. Could you please see whether there are existing tags that are applicable and try to think about the utility of new tags before creating them?

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you mean trade volume or transferred volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this site, data is shown graphically but can be downloaded in *.CSV or *.XLS file as well... http://data.bitcoinity.org/markets/volume/30d?c=e&t=b